# How to resolve a 'Type mismatch' error in scala?

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and am trying to resolve a 'Type mismatch' error that I am getting when I switched from using SendGridEmailParams to SendGridHandlebarEmailParams.  Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
Type mismatch, expected: ReferenceNodeMessage.GetCategoriesResponse => Future[NotInferedS], actual: ReferenceNodeMessage.GetCategoriesResponse => Any
```

[image]

Here is where I made the switch from SendGridEmailParams to SendGridHandlebarEmailParams :

```
  private lazy val redemptionSendGridEmailParams = SendGridHandlebarEmailParams(
    templateName = redemptionEmailTemplateName,
    subject = "Verify ServiceProviderName completed your Category service"
  )
  private lazy val requestAQuoteSendGridEmailParams = SendGridHandlebarEmailParams(
    templateName = requestAQuoteEmailTemplateName,
    subject = "Verify ServiceProviderName completed your Category project"
  )
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Your for has the wrong syntax, change your "=" to "<-"

Comment: Which line exactly?

Comment: What is the expected and actual types? You remove the return type of the function so error will go but you should know what do you want to return!!

Comment: @FairyQueen my bad I am blind, do you have a yield? it is hard to say what is wrong without knowing all the types, aka having the code